# Ho to filter keys and values from a python dictionary based on conditions?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have python dictionary with the below items :

```
> ...
>     {'HostName': 'DEMOBDDBX00100.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'SUCCESS'}
>     {'HostName': 'DEMOBDDBX00200.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'SUCCESS'}
>     {'HostName': 'DEMOBDDBX10101.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'FAILURE'}
>     {'HostName': 'DEMOBDDBX10102.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'FAILURE'}
>     {'HostName': 'DEMOBDDBX10201.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'FAILURE'}
>     {'HostName': 'DEMOBDDBX10202.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'FAILURE'}
>     {'HostName': 'DEMOBDMBX00100.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'SUCCESS'}
>     {'HostName': 'DEMOBDMBX00200.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'SUCCESS'}
>     {'HostName': 'DEMOBDMBX10101.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'FAILURE'}
>     {'HostName': 'DEMOBDMBX10102.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'FAILURE'}
>     {'HostName': 'DEMODACRT10100.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'SUCCESS'}
>     {'HostName': 'DEMODACRT10200.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'SUCCESS'}
>     {'HostName': 'DEMODACTS10101.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'SUCCESS'}
>     {'HostName': 'DEMODACTS10102.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'SUCCESS'}
>     {'HostName': 'DEMOKLIRT10100.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'SUCCESS'}
>     {'HostName': 'DEMOKLIRT10200.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'SUCCESS'}
>     {'HostName': 'DEMOKNORT10100.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'SUCCESS'}
>     {'HostName': 'DEMOKNORT10200.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'SUCCESS'}
>     {'HostName': 'DEMOKOSRT10200.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'SUCCESS'}
>     {'HostName': 'DEMOLABTS10300.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'SUCCESS'}
>     {'HostName': 'DEMOLABTS10400.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'SUCCESS'}
> ...
```

I need to filter out the values in Hostname only if the `BackupStatus == "FAILURE"`
I need the output as:

```
    {'HostName': 'DEMOBDMBX10101.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'FAILURE'}
    {'HostName': 'DEMOBDDBX10101.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'FAILURE'}
    {'HostName': 'DEMOBDDBX10102.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'FAILURE'}
    {'HostName': 'DEMOBDDBX10201.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'FAILURE'}
    {'HostName': 'DEMOBDDBX10202.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'FAILURE'}`
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: This is not a dictionary. The individual records are dictionary, but you have not mentioned what is the object which contains these dictionaries. That is what you want to filter. Please add what that object is.

Answer (score 0):

This does not look like a dictionary but a list of dictionaries.

If that's the case, it seems you want to obtain a sub-list with only those elements (dictionaries) that have `BackupStatus` equal to `FAILURE`. So you could do something like this:

```
recs = [
    {'HostName': 'DEMOBDDBX00100.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'SUCCESS'},
    {'HostName': 'DEMOBDDBX00200.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'SUCCESS'},
    {'HostName': 'DEMOBDDBX10101.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'FAILURE'},
    ...
]
failed_recs = [v for v in recs if v['BackupStatus'] == 'FAILURE']
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider utilizing a [**list comprehension**](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> data = [
...   {'HostName': 'DEMOBDDBX00100.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'SUCCESS'},
...   {'HostName': 'DEMOBDDBX00200.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'SUCCESS'},
...   {'HostName': 'DEMOBDDBX10101.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'FAILURE'},
...   {'HostName': 'DEMOBDDBX10102.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'FAILURE'},
...   {'HostName': 'DEMOBDDBX10201.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'FAILURE'},
...   {'HostName': 'DEMOBDDBX10202.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'FAILURE'},
...   {'HostName': 'DEMOBDMBX00100.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'SUCCESS'},
...   {'HostName': 'DEMOBDMBX00200.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'SUCCESS'},
...   {'HostName': 'DEMOBDMBX10101.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'FAILURE'},
...   {'HostName': 'DEMOBDMBX10102.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'FAILURE'},
...   {'HostName': 'DEMODACRT10100.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'SUCCESS'},
...   {'HostName': 'DEMODACRT10200.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'SUCCESS'},
...   {'HostName': 'DEMODACTS10101.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'SUCCESS'},
...   {'HostName': 'DEMODACTS10102.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'SUCCESS'},
...   {'HostName': 'DEMOKLIRT10100.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'SUCCESS'},
...   {'HostName': 'DEMOKLIRT10200.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'SUCCESS'},
...   {'HostName': 'DEMOKNORT10100.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'SUCCESS'},
...   {'HostName': 'DEMOKNORT10200.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'SUCCESS'},
...   {'HostName': 'DEMOKOSRT10200.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'SUCCESS'},
...   {'HostName': 'DEMOLABTS10300.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'SUCCESS'},
...   {'HostName': 'DEMOLABTS10400.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'SUCCESS'},
... ]
>>> [d for d in data if d['BackupStatus'] == 'FAILURE']
[{'HostName': 'DEMOBDDBX10101.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'FAILURE'}, 
 {'HostName': 'DEMOBDDBX10102.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'FAILURE'}, 
 {'HostName': 'DEMOBDDBX10201.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'FAILURE'}, 
 {'HostName': 'DEMOBDDBX10202.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'FAILURE'}, 
 {'HostName': 'DEMOBDMBX10101.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'FAILURE'}, 
 {'HostName': 'DEMOBDMBX10102.demo', 'BackupStatus': 'FAILURE'}]
```